# Webelement.click in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium to do the UI automation for a web application.

**1) My doubt is**

when i use the `click()` method like, `right_btn.click()` whether it just clicks the `right_btn` and comes out or it just waits for the underlying actions to be completed before it moves out???

**bcoz i read this**

When i googled for `WebElement.click()` http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html it says like, it gets blocked whenever the `click()` involves opening a new page but here it doesnt opens a new page rather it involves in service call.

**2) What i actually want to know?**

I want to know this actually to calculate the latency involved in carrying out each actions in the UI. Is there any way to calculate the latency for each UI actions, just like we can see the latency time when we use `inspect element` in `chrome`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is hard to read. I would suggest summarizing your question in a single sentence and then putting that at the start of your question. Then, following the summary, describe the steps you've undertaken to attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can make a `Date a = new date()` object with the current time, just before your `right_btn.click()` and then wait for the resulting page to open, (if in a new tab/window - switch to it) and then find some element on that page

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));
```

After that returns the element, make another `Date b = new Date()`

The latency is the difference in milliseconds `int millis = b-a;`

Yes, a small part of that total time is Selenium searching for the 2nd element, but I'm afraid this might be the best you can do with java/selenium for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if I understood your question exactly 
How to calculate Latency is hard , but for intercepting calls you can use browserMobProxy in your code and check if particular call is complete and move on